# Weird behavior of File.pathseperator java

Tags: java

I am developing a program in Java that associates with a file, so I use`File.separator` in order to manage it.

The weird fact is that everywhere I call it, it returns the `\` as it should since I am working on Windows except in the last function I use it. There, it returns the `;`. I'll give you a piece of my code although I believe it won't help much. Is there anything else I should know to fix the problem?

```
 System.out.println("File:" +source+"\n");

     String filename= f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf(File.pathSeparator)+1,f.getName().length());//here at printing I get /
     System.out.println("Filename:" +filename+"\n");

     InputStream is = null;
     OutputStream os = null;
     try {
            is = new FileInputStream(source);
            os = new FileOutputStream(output+ File.pathSeparator + filename);//here I get ;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `File.pathSeparator` *is* `;` on Windows. For example, you might have:

```
PATH=c:\Utils;c:\SomethingElse
```

`File.pathSeparator` is `;` on Windows and `:` on Unix.

You're thinking of `File.separator` which would be `\` on Windows and `/` on Unix.

Here's a simple way of seeing that:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("File.separator is " + File.separator);
        System.out.println("File.pathSeparator is " + File.pathSeparator);
    }    
}
```

(In your first sentence you even talk about `File.separator` - but then you use `File.pathSeparator` in the code.)

Note that if you use the methods within the `File` class, you typically don't need to specify the separator at all - it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I suspect something like:

```
File file = new File(f.getName());
File outputFile = new File(output, file.getName());
// Now use outputFile
```

... would work better and be cleaner.

Comment: Thx for your answer , but it still confuses me why in the first instance of the code above it returns \ and on the second ; . It should return the same character on both cases right?

Comment: @Mario: It doesn't - you're confusing yourself somehow, but as we don't know anything about `f` (not even its type) it's hard to know what you're doing wrong. You say "here at printing I get /" but you haven't explained what you're printing or how.

Comment: I see now. I will recheck my code! And yes you are right I didn't know that there is this overloaded constructor of file. Thx a lot for your help at both points!